# Find Bugs - Not finding bugs

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

I have recently set up find bugs in eclipse to see what reports it generates. Ive set all the settings to be as sensitive as possible. If i create a small application that writes to a file and do not close the stream it picks it up which is all good.

However, using a project that has been written where we no there are a couple of bugs, especially in the output, we get no errors at all (in terms of find bugs)

I was wondering if anyone could run this through their version and report whether I may have find bugs set up incorrectly or whether in fact it could find no bugs?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SpellUtil {

    private final static String teenSpelling[] = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three",
        "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven",
        "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen",
        "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"};

    private final static String centSpelling[] = {"Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty",
        "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"};

    private final static String suffixSpelling[] = {
        "", // Dummy! no level 0 (added for nicer indexing in code)
        "", // Nothing for level 1
        " Thousand, ", " Million, ", " Billion, ", " Trillion, ", " Quadrillion, ",
        " Quintillion, "};



    public static String spell(int number) {

        int rem, placeIndicator = 1;
        boolean isNegative = false;
        List<String> spelling = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (number < 0) {
            isNegative = true;
            number = Math.abs(number);
        }

        while (number > 0) {
            rem = number % 1000;
            number = number / 1000;

            spelling.add(suffixSpelling[placeIndicator]);

            try {
                spelling.add(spellBelow1000(rem));
            } catch (SpellingException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            placeIndicator++;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (isNegative) sb.append("Minus ");
        for (int i = spelling.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sb.append(spelling.get(i));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String spellBelow1000(int number) throws SpellingException {

        if (number < 0 || number >= 1000)
            throw new SpellingException("Expecting a number between 0 and 999: " + number);

        if (number < 20) {
            // if number is a teen,
            // find it in teen table and return its equivalent text (word).
            return teenSpelling[number];
        } else if (number < 100) {
            // otherwise, if it is a cent,
            // find the most (div) and least (rem) significant digits (MSD/LSD)
            int div = (int) number / 10;
            int rem = (int) number % 10;

            if (rem == 0) {
                // if LSD is zero, return the cent key word directly (like
                // fifty).
                return centSpelling[div-2];
            } else {
                // otherwise, return the text as cent-teen (like fifty-one)
                return centSpelling[div-2] + "-" + teenSpelling[rem];
            }
        } else {
            // otherwise, it is a mil;
            // find it's MSD and remaining cent.
            int div = number / 100;
            int rem = (int) number % 100;  // TODO will findbugs detect unnecessary (int)?

            // Prepare the mil prefix:
            String milText = teenSpelling[div] + " Hundred";

            // decide whether to append the cent tail or not.
            if (rem == 0) {
                // if it does have a non-zero cent, that's it.
                // return the mil prefix, for example three hundred:
                return milText;
            } else {
                // otherwise, spell the cent and append it to mil prefix.
                // (now, rem is a cent).
                // For example, three Hundred and Sixty-Four:
                return milText + " and " + spellBelow1000(rem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which specific bug should it find, but doesn't? Do you think FindBugs will find any kind of bug your program could have?

Comment: no - i just assumed that it would at least throw a couple of warnings or something

Comment: And where do you expect that bug to be?

Comment: well i know the application doesnt actually work but i didnt no if it would mention warnings about something like this `int rem = (int) number % 100;  // TODO will findbugs detect unnecessary (int)?`

Comment: basically the reason i am doing this is because i need to do a presentation of find bugs and i need an application to generate some bugs to show how it works :D i was hoping one we made a while ago that didnt work would throw some!

Comment: @SkyR how about downloading some open source projects and running findbugs against their code bases? You might be able to present different kind of errors. You could even fix some of them by submitting pull requests :)

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation to find a bug in this line:

```
int rem = (int) number % 100;  // TODO will findbugs detect unnecessary (int)?
```

is WRONG because the result of a `%` operation is not an integer in general.

In `C` and `C++`, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands, but *in Java, it also accepts floating-point operands.* This means statements such as `double x = 8.2 % 4;` are quite valid in Java and the result could be a non-integer value. (`0.1999999999999993` in this case)

Please see the Java language specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

Comment: How can the result be anything other than an `int` when both `number` and `100` are of type `int`?

Comment: The result of a `%` operation is not an integer **in general**. The result would be of type `int`, though, if both of the operands are of type `int`.

Comment: FindBugs knows the types of the operands in this case. Since the compiler does too, it probably drops the cast and FB never even sees it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a problem with findbugs configuration. I suggest using Findbugs via Sonar. It is much more easy to configure and you get checkstyle, pmd and a system for managing and resolving violations.

[Sonar findbugs page](http://www.sonarsource.org/tag/findbugs/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you misunderstanding what FindBugs does and what its capabilities are.

Basically, FindBugs parses each class to produce a parse-tree - an in-memory representation of the structure of the program.  Then attempts to find places in the tree that match known patterns which represent incorrect or questionable programming.  For example:

```
    if (someString == "42") {
        ....
    }
```

FindBugs will most likely tell you comparing strings using the '==' operator here is wrong.  What it has done is look through the class for any expression node  where the operator is '==' and one or both of the operands is a String.  It will repeat this procedure for a large number of patterns that it has been programmed to detect and report.  Some will be more complicated than this one, but basically, FindBug is only doing a form of structural pattern matching.

What FindBugs does not and cannot do is to understand what your program is actually supposed to do.  So for example:

```
    public boolean isOdd(int arg) {
        return (arg % 2) == 0;
    }
```

This is obviously incorrect to anyone who understands simple mathematics ... but FindBugs won't notice it.  That is because FindBugs has no idea what the method is actually supposed to do.  Furthermore, it is not capable of doing the elementary semantic analysis that is required to figure out that the code doesn't implement the math.

---

> The reason I am doing this is because I need to do a presentation of find bugs and I need an application to generate some bugs to show how it works.

Maybe you need to cheat a bit:

- Read the Findbugs documentation to understand the things that it is capable of finding.
- Write some "toy" applications with bugs that you know Findbugs can find for you.

It is also worthwhile including examples that you know it won't find ... so that you can explain the limitations of Findbugs.

Comment: Also, some features of FindBugs are only available once you've added annotations such as `@Nonnull` and `@ThreadSafe` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

What findbugs does is to look for some common mistakes that could (and most probably would) lead to unexpected/unwanted behavior. Most of those errors are technical or wrong use of java and its API. A list of all findbugs checks can be found [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) In other words if you did something you don't wanted in a right way, findbugs would not detect it. In your code I can't see anything that would be detected by findbugs. The unnecessary cast you mentioned in your comments is not a findbugs rule because it doesn't change the behavior of your code. It is more of a style or efficiency error and would be detected by tools like [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) or [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).